# What is wrong with this logic statement (Android)?

Tags: android, logic

I can't see why the following logic isn't working:

```
                if (cursorCount > 1 && (!"x".equals(componentType) || !"y".equals(componentType))){
                        message.append("s");
                    }
```

So I want to to print 's' if the cursor count is over 1 but only when the componentType does not equal x or y..

Seems to work for the cases that are y but not x interestingly.

Confused.com! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
if (cursorCount > 1 && !("x".equals(componentType) || "y".equals(componentType)))
```

Equivalently you can do

```
if (cursorCount > 1 && !"x".equals(componentType) && !"y".equals(componentType))
```

This comes from an application of deMorgan's law to your logic.

I believe these more closely matche your English description of what you want.

**Edit:**

To clear up the confusion, let's analyze the logic of the final part of your English description:

> ...but only when the componentType does not equal x or y.

Another way to state the same thing is "componentType is neither x nor y". In order to translate this into code, we should go a step further and reword this condition as "It is not the case that either componentType is x or comonentType is y." This final version suggests that the correct boolean formula is of the form

```
!(A || B)
```

This is very different from your original code which is of the form

```
!A || !B
```

Note that my final rewording is more verbose, but the extra verbiage makes the logic more clear.

Another way to analyze the logic is to look at the code you gave:

```
!"x".equals(componentType) || !"y".equals(componentType)
```

Let's look at a few examples:

1. `"x".equals(componentType) is true. This means the negation is false. It also means that` "y".equals(componentType)` is false and *it's* negation is true. Therefore, your code evaluates to true.
2. `"y".equals(componentType) is true. This means the negation is false. It also means that` "x".equals(componentType)` is false and *it's* negation is true. Therefore, your code evaluates to true.
3. Neither `"x".equals(componentType) nor` "y".equals(componentType) is true. This means both negations are false and your code evaluates to false.

Note that your code evaluates to true in both cases 1. and 2. This does not give the same result as expected from your English description.

Comment: Cheers for quick response.  The first option worked fine. Am I being dumb though - how could the second option work as I am testing for: this AND (!this or !this).. Think I am confusing myself!!

Comment: @Scamparelli See my edit for an explanation of the logic behind what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a '(' before your "x" condition that shouldn't be there. Then remove one of them from the end of the whole `if` statement. You should wrap those conditions that belong together in "()" because it is confusing as heck to read like this.

if ((cursorCount > 1 && !"x".equals(componentType)) || (!"y".equals(componentType)))

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((cursorCount > 1 && !"x".equals(componentType)) 
|| (cursorCount > 1 && !"y".equals(componentType))) 
  message.append("s");
```

or you could nest them if it'd make it easier

```
if (cursorCount > 1)
  if (componentType!="y" || componentType!="x")
    message.append("s");
```

This would make it easier to understand and with less fallacies.