# How does if or work?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

How does if-statements in android programming work with the or (`||`)?

My code looks like this:

```
if (!phone.equals("Note II") || !phone.equals("S3"))
```

And now the code that only will be executed if not Note II and S3 gets executed anyway. It only works if I have one statement and searching the web it says I should be able to have or but I don't know how...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you understand what `||` does?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267678/what-is-wrong-with-this-logic-statement-android/14267710#14267710) to a similar question for an explanation about the logic you are using here.

Answer (score 9):

As written, your condition is true if the phone is not a Note II **or** if it is not an S3. Since a phone cannot be both a Note II and an S3, the condition is always true!

What you probably mean is for the condition to be true if the phone is not a Note II **and** not an S3.

```
if (!phone.equals("Note II") && !phone.equals("S3"))
```

Comment: Haha, didn't really think it through. Thanks man! Will accept when I can.

Comment: Or equivalently, it could be `if (!(phone.equals("Note II") || phone.equals("S3")))`.

Answer (score 0):

duskwuff answered your basic question.  You probably want **and**, not **or**.  The reason your code gets executed *if not Note II* is that the double-bar `||` OR operator only evaluates the first expression, if it turns out to be true.  At run-time, there's usually no reason to check the second expression.